# How to convert a sample from vst to a pattern in FL studio

Tags: fl-studio

On FL Studio, some VST plugin (Wizo) has rhythms, but it output to Track(mixer) directly.

I want that to output as pattern in FL studio and use it in the tracks.
Or what is the proper way to use these rhythms?
Sorry I am a very new to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wizo is a synth which outputs audio, not midi. You can only (therefore) route the audio to another track and then record that should you wish to then manipulate the result further down the track. It's probably not the best way to go about it - just use wizo in the way it was intended - send midi events to the plugin and then mix the resulting audio.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use the rhythms comes with wizo in a song, not creating or manipulating them.
I export them as wav file to be re-used, is this too stupid or should be something else you meant by "route the audio to another track and then record"?

Comment: It might be possible to use one of the recording options inside of FL, but basically it's easier to just use the output of wizo into the mixer. The midi input to wizo will be consistent each time. It's probably better to use the midi input and mix the output so that if you decide to change tempo, the output will reflect the new tempo.